# Postgresql settings not changing after editing postgresql.conf file. Postgresql 13. Debian 11

Tags: postgresql, logging, debian

Empirically, it was revealed that the parameters `log_min_duration_statement = 0` and `logging_collector = on` are indeed set in the pg_settings table. But the parameters in the pg_settings table do not react to changes in postgresql.conf. After changing postgresql.conf, postgresql restarted with the `systemctl restart postgresql` command. In the postgresql.conf file parameter `logging_collector = off`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some simple possible mistakes that you could have made:

- edit the wrong `postgresql.conf`
- restart the wrong server

If you can rule out these explanations, the setting from `postgresql.conf` must have been overridden somewhere else. Find out where with

```
SELECT name, setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name IN ('logging_collector', 'log_min_duration_statement');
```

The last three columns tell you where the setting originates.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the configuration is read from the /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf file, while I made changes to the /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf file. Thank you very much for your help!